# Why Codemagic does not let me execute a build?

Tags: ios, cicd, codemagic

I am trying to configure codemagic for CI/CD, I have created the YAML necessary to execute the pipelines where there are different scripts in a pipeline like this YAML:

```
    workflows:
  develop:
    instance_type: mac_pro
    environment:
      Xcode: 14.2
  
  
  
  
    scripts:
      - name: say hello
        script: echo "Hello Codemagician!"
        
      - name: Run iOS tests
        script: |
          set -e # exit on first failed command

          xcode-project run-tests \
              --workspace ${XCODE_WORKSPACE?} \
              --scheme ${XCODE_SCHEME?} \
              --device "iPhone 12"
        test_report: build/ios/test/*.xml
        
# pipeline for main
  main:
    instance_type: mac_pro
    environment:
      xcode: 14.2

    scripts:
      - name: say hello
        script: echo "Hello Codemagician!"
        
      - name: Run iOS tests
        script: |
          set -e # exit on first failed command

          xcode-project run-tests \
              --workspace ${XCODE_WORKSPACE?} \
              --scheme ${XCODE_SCHEME?} \
              --device "iPhone 12"
        test_report: build/ios/test/*.xml
        
      - name: Add provisioning profiles
        script: |
          set -e # exit on first failed command

          PROFILES_HOME="$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"
          mkdir -p "$PROFILES_HOME"
          echo ${PROVISIONING_PROFILE?} | base64 --decode > "$PROFILES_HOME/$(uuidgen).mobileprovision"
      - name: Add signing certificate
        script: |
          set -e # exit on first failed command

          echo ${CERTIFICATE?} | base64 --decode > /tmp/certificate.p12
          keychain initialize
          keychain add-certificates \
              --certificate /tmp/certificate.p12 \
              --certificate-password ${CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD?}
      - name: Increment build number
        script: agvtool new-version -all $BUILD_NUMBER
      - name: Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
        script: xcode-project use-profiles
      - name: Build ipa for distribution
        script: xcode-project build-ipa \
                    --workspace "${XCODE_WORKSPACE?}" \
                    --scheme "${XCODE_SCHEME?}"
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
  
    publishing:
      app_store_connect:
        api_key: $APP_STORE_CONNECT_PRIVATE_KEY
        key_id: $APP_STORE_CONNECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER
        issuer_id: $APP_STORE_CONNECT_ISSUER_ID
        submit_to_testflight: true
        beta_groups:
          - Beta Testers
```

when I launch the build then this happens:
[image: error]

I think codemagic is accessible in different environments freely. I don't know how I can fix this issue and I´d want to see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

on free plan you can use Apple M1 machine.

Replace `instance_type: mac_pro` with `instance_type: mac_mini_m1` (or remove this line at all).